# Monic Quadratics Please help xD

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write $a^4 + 4$ as a product of two monic quadratics with integer coefficients.

Comment: No, we're not helping, unless you show your workings towards the solution. (Even if it is rather feeble.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, in addition to idriskameni's solution.  Consider that the four roots of $a^4+4 = 0$ are $r_{1,2,3,4} = \pm 1 \pm i$ (all combinations).  The monic quadratics will be products of the form $(a-r_i)(a-r_j)$, but in order to have real coefficients, we require that both $r_i+r_j$ and $r_ir_j$ be real.

By inspection, this occurs with the pair $1+i$ and $1-i$, and also with $-1+i$ and $-1-i$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$x^4 +4$$

Let $g(x)=x^2+ax+b$, $f(x)=x^2+cx+d$ and consider its multiplication:

$$g(x)f(x)= x^4 + (a+c)x^3+ (b+d+ac)x^2 + (bc+ad)x + bd$$

Now by considering the coefficients for each degree, we have the following sistem:

- $a+c=0$
- $b+d+ac=0$
- $bc+ad=0$
- $bd=4$

Then we have, $a=-c$ from (1), then putting it on (3) we obtain $b=d$. From (4) we have $b=d=2$. Puting it on (2) we have $4 = a^2$, so $a=\pm 2$. Hence $c=\pm 2$.

Then we have:

$$x^4+4= (x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$$